Why do i get dev/kvm : No such device after installing kvm?
I am getting the error while running an emulator on my WSL Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on Windows
The error came when i already installed kvm in my ubuntu server and trying to create an avd device.
lsmod | grep kvm does not emit anything.
while modprobe kvm_intel and modprobe kvm_amd successfully running with no result.
$ lsmod | grep kvm

$ dmesg | grep kvm
[    1.396487] kvm: no hardware support
[    1.396493] kvm: no hardware support

$ modprobe kvm_intel

$ modprobe kvm_amd

Creating AVD Device
$ avdmanager create avd -n device \
--device pixel -k "system-images;android-33;google_apis_playstore;x86_64

Running AVD Device
$ emulator @device
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-noid/emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 9068
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.15.0 (build_id 11906825) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/noid/.android_sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-noid/emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 9068
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
ERROR   | x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: Could not open /dev/kvm : No such device
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.


The device entry has nothing to do with what packages you have installed; it's all about which kernel modules have been successfully loaded.

So apt-get has nothing whatsoever to do with it, whereas we need to know what lsmod | grep kvm and dmesg | grep kvm emit, and whether you can successfully run either modprobe kvm_intel or modprobe kvm_amd.

Over on Server Fault, see How to run kvm nested in WSL2 or VMware?. Indeed, I'm tempted to argue that this question is off-topic here and would be better asked there or on [unix.se]; kvm isn't a tool specific to software development or exclusively used by developers.

kvm: no hardware support -- well, there you are; if the kernel module checks the CPU and finds that it isn't supporting the necessary flags, you're not going to get any further until that's fixed. If you're already in a VM then you may need to turn on nested virtualization in the host to get that hardware support; that's what the cross-site (ServerFault) duplicate linked above covers. (That said, be sure that you ran the dmesg | grep after running the modprobe -- the order in which they're presented in the question makes that a little unclear).
